# Maximum value for $F(y)=\int_0^1[y'\sin(\pi y)-(y-t)^2]dt$?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

This is what I have done thus far:

$F(y)=\int_0^1[y'\sin(\pi y)-(y-t)^2]dt=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1[(\cos(\pi y))\frac{d}{dt}]dt-\int_0^1(y-t)^2dt$

(as $-\frac{1}{\pi}[(\cos(\pi y))\frac{d}{dt}]=-\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot -\pi y'\sin(\pi y)=y'\sin(\pi y)$)

I then used the fundamental theorem of calculus to determine the first part of the integral and determined the second part simply as a polynomial.

$=-\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\cos(\pi y)-(y^2-y+\frac{1}{3})$

Then, to find the maximum of $F(y)$, I took the derivative and equated it to $0$.

$F'(y)=\sin(\pi y)-2y+1=0$

However, I'm not sure how I should use the above equation to solve for y. Also, did I use the fundamental theorem of calculus correctly above?

*Edit: $y(t)=t$

Comment: Is $\;y\;$ a function of $\;t\;$ or just a variable?

Comment: y is a function of t. Thank you for making sure I clarify!

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(y)=F_1(y)+F_2(y)$, where
$$
F_1(y)=\int_0^1y'\sin(\pi y)\,dt\quad \text{and}\quad F_2(y)=-\int_0^1(y-t)^2dt. \tag{1}
$$
$F_2(y)$ is clearly maximized by $y(t)=t$, $t\in[0,1]$, for which $F_2=0$. $F_1(y)$, on the other hand, only depends on $y(0)$ and $y(1)$ (provided $y(t)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$):
$$
F_1(y)=\int_{y(0)}^{y(1)}\sin(\pi y)\,dy=-\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\cos(\pi y(1))-
\cos(\pi y(0))\right]. \tag{2}
$$
$F_1$ is maximized if $\cos(\pi y(1))=-1$ and $\cos(\pi y(0))=1$, that is, if $y(1)$ is an odd integer and $y(0)$ is an even integer, in which case $F_1=\frac{2}{\pi}$. Fortunately, the function that maximizes $F_2$ satisfies these conditions. Therefore, the maximum value of $F(y)$ is $\frac{2}{\pi}$, and it is attained by the function $y(t)=t,$ $t\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

By the Euler-Lagrange equation in the Calculus of variations,
$$f_y-\frac{d}{dt}(f_{y'})\\
=\pi\cos(\pi y)y'-2(y-t)-\frac{d}{dt}(\sin\pi y)\\
=-2(y-t)=0.$$